# ArcGIS Map Viewer Adding decimal places or including seperator in configure pop ups

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

I am trying to find the equivalent of configure pop ups as seen below in the new Map Viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Berend said it is on the right of the "Map Viewer" (The old one is now called "Classic" by ESRI). The "Fields" button is on the right.  The popup configuration for a numeric field looks like this in English:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SteveC and Berend for the insight and solution!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about the new map viewer?

The field display settings can be configured by selecting the layer, then clicking the *Configure Fields* button on the right: [image: Configure fields button], and finally selecting the field.

Here's what it looks like in Dutch:

[image: Configure field form]